# Floating text in XELaTeX

Tags: floats, xetex

I have the following section header which uses two different font sizes.

[image: Screenshot of TeX render]

I'd like to add a series of 2-3 vertical lines of text off to the far right, anchored to the top of the section's bounding box, and completely independent of the font sizes used on the far left.

Something like this (*note the lines edited into the left of the render screenshot*):

[image: Screenshot of TeX render]

How might I achieve this?

Apologies for the inelegance of the TeX; I've only been using it for a couple of days. (I'm using XƎLaTeX.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand*{\sepline}{%
  \par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
    \begingroup
      \color{gray!55}%
      \hrule width\linewidth height 0.1mm
    \endgroup
  \vspace{3mm}
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\color{gray!185}

\setlength{\parindent}{3em}

\begingroup
    \setmainfont{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.5mm}
    {\color{gray!160}\fontspec[Scale=1.55]{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}Subject\par\vspace{0.4mm}}
    {
        \setlength{\parindent}{1.7mm}
        \color{gray!200}
        \begin{tabular}{ l l }
            To: & {\hspace{1mm}DEF} \\
            From: & {\hspace{1mm}ABC} \\
            Sent: & {\hspace{1mm}Tue 24th Oct 2014 12:56:04PM}
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \vspace{0mm}
\endgroup

\sepline

\noindent Test content

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you give us a little drawing of your desired result? What do you mean by vertical lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED to line up top of right stack with top of "Subject"

Following "Subject" in the header, I used a right-aligned `\Longunderstack` for the right-hand text, pushing it to the right with an `\hfill`.  I had to `\smash` it so that it did not affect the vertical spacing on the left.  Also, because the word "Subject" was scaled up by a factor of 1.55, I had to vertically raise the `\Longunderstack` by `0.55\baselineskip` to line up the tops of those two quantities (otherwise the bottom of "Subject" aligned with bottom of "Line 1").

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand*{\sepline}{%
  \par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
    \begingroup
      \color{gray!55}%
      \hrule width\linewidth height 0.1mm
    \endgroup
  \vspace{3mm}
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\color{gray!185}

\setlength{\parindent}{3em}

\begingroup
    \setmainfont{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.5mm}
    {\color{gray!160}{\fontspec[Scale=1.55]{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}Subject}
    \hfill
    {\footnotesize\smash{\raisebox{0.55\baselineskip}{\Longunderstack[r]{
      Line one\\
      Line two\\
      Line three\\
      Line four
    }}}}
\par\vspace{0.4mm}}
    {
        \setlength{\parindent}{1.7mm}
        \color{gray!200}
        \begin{tabular}{ l l }
            To: & {\hspace{1mm}DEF} \\
            From: & {\hspace{1mm}ABC} \\
            Sent: & {\hspace{1mm}Tue 24th Oct 2014 12:56:04PM}
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \vspace{0mm}
\endgroup

\sepline

\noindent Test content

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty awesome - it's practically *exactly* what I'm looking for... except (and I could've made this clearer) I want the text on the right to align with the top edge of the "Subject" text. How might I do that? I tried `[t]`-aligning the `tabular` and that almost works but I'm not sure how to tune it.

Comment: @i336_  Please see revision.  I had to add the stack after "Subject" rather than after your `tabular`.  Also had to use a `\Longunderstack` rather than a `\Longstack`, and finally had to raise the stack by `0.55\baselineksip` to account for the 1.55 scale of "Subject"